# JOOQ empty condition

Tags: java, jooq

Is there way to define empty condition which produces nothing in output sql query? Now, for default condition I use `trueCondition()`

```
private static Condition limitCondition(Integer offset, Integer count) {
    Condition limitCondition = trueCondition();
    if (count != null && offset != null) {
        limitCondition = rowNum.between(offset, count + offset);
    } else if (count == null && offset != null) {
        limitCondition = rowNum.greaterOrEqual(offset);
    } else if (count != null && offset == null) {
        limitCondition = rowNum.lessOrEqual(count);
    }
    return limitCondition;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is [`DSL.noCondition()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#noCondition()) starting with jOOQ 3.11, which can act as an identity for both `AND` and `OR` operators, and doesn't produce any output unless strictly required (e.g. when projecting it in `SELECT`), in case of which it acts like [`DSL.trueCondition()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#trueCondition())

For more details, see:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6817
- https://blog.jooq.org/create-empty-optional-sql-clauses-with-jooq/

Comment: thank you, Lukas. another question is there plan to implement using offset without limit clause?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit too late for this but on 3.14 version, there is a static method you can use.

```
Condition result = trueCondition();
```

refer: [jooq documentation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/)